# Portlet for google maps and map with filters

Tags: google-maps, plone

I've tried 3 different type of addon to find a portlet for show the maps, but none of them works.
I've tried collective.geo.bundle, Products.Maps and Products.ATGoogleMaps.
My goal is the have a map with filter like this:
http://www.orcogroup.com/company/activities
and an addon that has a portlet for the maps.
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Plone is open source, only your imagination is the limit what you can do with it. So, yes there is a solution. However, sometimes it takes skills and resources to accomplish those goals :)

Because your use case is not common, Plone or its add-ons might not provide such functionality out of the box. In your case you are looking very advanced AJAX and specific functionality.

I have seen some similar maps on a Plone site:

http://iwlearn.net/iw-projects/@@project-map-view.html

In this case it looks like they use some or all of the following packages

```
collective.geo.contentlocations
collective.geo.file
collective.geo.flexitopic
collective.geo.geographer
collective.geo.geopoint
collective.geo.index
collective.geo.kml
collective.geo.mapcontent
collective.geo.mapwidget
collective.geo.openlayers
collective.geo.settings
```

You might still need to customize the functionality a lot to get the output what you want from it. It this case you need to write an add-on layer customizing Plone functionality further

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getstarted/index.html